# How to move the main document part of a word file to the header part of another word file?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, word-2010

How can I copy the main document part of a word document to the header part of another word document? Moving the header part from a file to another is explained here [How to: Replace the Header in a Word Processing Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc546917.aspx), but simply replacing the line

```
 headerPart.FeedData(firstHeader.GetStream());
```

with : `headerPart.FeedData(wordProcessingDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream());`

does not work.

Regards